# Can I get a Taiwanese visa being a Pakistani passport holder?

Tags: visas, paperwork, pakistani-citizens, taiwan

I'm a Pakistani artist. I have been selected for an exhibition in Taiwan. I want to know if can I get a Taiwanese visa, being a Pakistani from Thailand?

Answer (score 4):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of Pakistan can obtain an
>   e-visa for a maximum stay of 30 days. The e-visa must have the
>   remark "P, Special Permission from MOFA" and passengers do not
>   require an invitation letter. Passengers must have a printed
>   e-visa confirmation.

The e-visa can be applied for [here](https://visawebapp.boca.gov.tw/BOCA_MRVWeb/). For Pakistanis, it is only issued "for the purpose of conducting business at the recommendation of local offices of the Taiwan External Trade Development Council (TAITRA)"

So ask your host to apply to the TAITRA for a recommendation through the Taiwanese Ministry of foreign affairs.

If they can't do that, you must apply for a regular visa, **which you can do in Thailand** as per [this official document of the Taipei Economic and Cultural Office in Thailand](http://www.roc-taiwan.org/uploads/sites/90/2017/11/Procedures-for-Nationals-of-the-Designated-Countries-Applying-for-Visas1.doc). However, the same approval as for an e-visa may be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

From your question I am assuming that you are a Pakistani citizen residing in Thailand interested in getting a visa for Taiwan.

Your best bet is to contact the [Consular Divison](http://www.roc-taiwan.org/th_en/post/20.html) of the Taipei Economic and Cultural Office in Thailand.

> Contact information: 02-6700200 ext 342 (Visa for Aliens)

PS: The reason why I recommend this is because some countries need you to apply from your home country. I am absolutely not sure about Taiwan (Republic of China). e.g. (Not an example of your scenario but) I know people who aren't Pakistani citizens and needed to apply for a 'Hajj' visa while in Pakistan; and, the Saudi Embassy simply declined to accommodate them saying that the Embassy in Pakistan provides services to local citizens or Saudi citizens only.

Comment: It's absolutely fine to apply in Thailand, confirmed through the second link in my answer

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can get a visa for Taiwan but the approval needs to come from their ministry of foreign affairs. Once the visa is approved, you must print the confirmation before flying to Taipei.

source: timatic.

Comment: That's just the requirement for an e-visa

Comment: For sticker visa as well the approval of MFA is required before a visa is stamped in passport. It is up to the passenger to get the sticker beforehand or fly with the printed approval.

Comment: Source for that? The official .doc file sure doesn't say so

Comment: @Coke, secondhand reports. Two Pakistani acquaintances recently applied for Taiwan visa and it was granted after approval from MFA. I think the reason the official .doc does not mention it because approval from MFA is part of the process for granting visa. Alternatively, they can get VoA if they have a printed confirmation that the said approval has already been given by the Taiwanese MFA.

Comment: No VOAs anymore (see Timatic), but e-visas are an option

Comment: Apologies, I meat to say e-visa not VoA.